# Why isn't this jQuery and Rails Javascript Partial working?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

```
$("#todos").append($("<%= escape_javascript(render("todo")) %>").find("form:eq[0]").children());
```

I'm sure the rendered partial has a form tag and it has child content, and yet, nothing gets added into `#todos`.

EDIT: Here's what is rendered by `escape_javascript(render("todo"))`

```
$("#todos").append($("<div class=\'todo\'>\n  <form accept-charset=\"UTF-8\" action=\"#\" class=\"new_todo\" id=\"new_todo\" method=\"post\"><div style=\"margin:0;padding:0;display:inline\"><input name=\"utf8\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"&#x2713;\" /><input name=\"authenticity_token\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"5jeoteBl1GwCw6t4jllDRVuragGoRh3wiodOV8jMgOQ=\" /><\/div>\n    <p>make laundry<\/p>\n  <\/form>\n<\/div>\n").find("form:eq[0]").children());
```

Comment: Try `alert($('#todos').length);`

Comment: I called that before and after append line, and both alerted 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>Maybe</del>Most probably it doesn't work because you used square brackets instead of round ones in `find()`

Should be

```
.find('form:eq(0)').children()
```